# apply focus state to list of elements in svelte

Tags: image, focus, svelte, onfocus, svelte-component

I have a list of buttons below. When a focus event occurs on the button I need it to switch to the first logo, else it should show the second logo. What would I put in my ternary operator below to make this happen?

IMAGE MAP

```js
import { Television_ChannelCode } from '@gql/schema';
import Logo1F from '@logos/Logo1F.svelte';
import Logo1U from '@logos/Logo1U.svelte';
import Logo2F from '@logos/Logo2F.svelte';
import Logo2U from '@logos/Logo2U.svelte';


const map = new Map<Television_ChannelCode, any>();
map.set(Television_ChannelCode.News, [Logo1F,Logo1U]);
map.set(Television_ChannelCode.Sports, [Logo2F, Logo2U]);

export const getLogoFromTelevisionChannelCode = (
    televisionChannelCode: Television_ChannelCode,
): any => {
    return map.get(televisionChannelCode);
};
```

CHOOSE IMAGE BASED ON FOCUS

```html
import { getLogoFromTelevisionChannelCode } from '@lib/

{#each shows as show, index}
    <button on:focus={(ev) => console.log(ev)}>
            <div>
                <svelte:component this={getLogoFromTelevisionChannelCode(
                            show.channel.channelCode)[(--HERE-- ? 0 : 1)]}
                />
            </div>
    </button>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not as simple as that. You need additional state to track the focus and since you are in a loop there are several options:

- Wrap contents of each in a new component which can track the focus state
- Add a property to each item
- Add a list or dictionary to the current component that associates each item with its focus state

The primary logic is always the same, update the item focus state in the `focus` event handler, then use it in the expression that selects the image.

If you want to switch back on `blur`, then you can simplify this, as you can only ever have one focused item, which can easily be tracked in a single state variable (e.g. using the index). You then just have to compare that against the `each` index.

[Here is simplified example](https://svelte.dev/repl/ecd17f7afd27469f85f08663ba7e8f91?version=3.49.0) of tracking the focus for a single item:

```html
<script>
    let items = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

    let focused = null;
</script>

{#each items as item, index}
    <div>
        <button on:focus={() => focused = index}
                on:blur={() => focused = focused == index ? null : focused}>
            {item}
            {#if focused == index}
                [Focused]
            {/if}
        </button>
    </div>
{/each}
```

Comment: sorry where is focustState being used or was it a typo? thanks!

Comment: Added that initially when tracking each item individually, but forgot to remove it again.